# Gstreamer: starting process 'command '/android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build''

Tags: android, gstreamer, ndk-build, gstreamer-1.0

I'm having a lot of problems with getting started using Android Studio to work with Gstreamer. So far, I have used Android Studio 2.2.3 and Gstreamer gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.10.2 library.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command '/android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build''
```

As for the Gradle Console displays:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
C:\Users\Ong Heng Gnee\AndroidStudioProjects\Gstreamer-Android-example-master\Gstreamer-Android-example-master\app\build/libs
C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.985 secs
```

I have used the default ndk-bundle but of no help too.

Original post used from this GitHub:

```
https://github.com/jaroslavas/Gstreamer-Android-Example
```

Comment: ***Update:
I have changed the commandLine code multiple times till I've reached this one and here are the end results.
//commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
            //commandLine'/android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build','-C',file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
    commandLine'C:\\android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build.cmd',

clang.exe: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold'
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_armeabi] Error 1

:app:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: are you sure that `ndkDir` specified properly? Please run `ndk-build` manually form `app/src/main/` dir and post output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-examples

1. You need to use ndk r12b
2. Use latest stable https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.10.2/
3. Set gstAndroidRoot
4. Build from console, assembleDebug etc

Happy building =)